# Using static void method to output in WriteLine

Tags: c#, methods, static, void

*If the title isn't accurate enough, please feel free to change it to something more well named.*

So i have a public static void:

```
public static void outputDictionaryContents(Dictionary<string, int> list)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}
```

and I am wanting to write out what it produce on a html file, it will output it fine on command prompt via:

```
outputDictionaryContents(sortedDict);
```

but when it comes to outputting it in my html with the following code:

```
tw.WriteLine("<td width\"480\">{0}</td>", outputDictionaryContents(sortedDict));
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(string, object)' has some invalid arguments
Argument '#2' cannon convert 'void' expression to type 'object'
```

So i'm not completely sure in what the best way is to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to write? Your method sends output to the Console, what is it you intend to place into your `<td>` cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method doesn't return a string - it writes to the console.

You could change it to return a string directly:

```
public static string GetDictionaryContents(Dictionary<string, int> list)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}{2}", pair.Key, pair.Value, Environment.NewLine);
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

That being said, if you're going to write this into an HTML output, you probably need to rethink what you want to write.  Writing newline separated info directly into a table cell is not going to format correctly...

You are more likely going to, at a minimum, want some additional formatting, or provide a separate terminator (such as a `<br />` instead of a newline)...

Comment: This worked perfectly man, and yeah when i ran it, i found out that it doesn't come out pretty and got rid of newline for the break.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes - it looks like you're expecting that method to *return* the string, when actually it's just printing it to the console.

Not only do you need to make your method return a string - you also need to think about how you would *format* it if you were using HTML. You almost certainly want to put each value on a separate line somehow - and there are various different ways of doing that.

You should decide what you want your method to do, exactly - is it for writing to a console, or generating HTML? Perhaps you want both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `outputDictionaryContents` has return type `void` so `outputDictionaryContents(sortedDict)` is an expression that evaluates to `void`. As such, it's not valid as a parameter to `TextWriter.WriteLine`.

The simplest approach is to change `outputDictionaryContents` to return a `string`.

```
public static string outputDictionaryContents(Dictionary<string, int> list) {
        var keyValuePairs = list.Select(
            kvp => String.Format("{0}, {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
        );
        return String.Join("\n", keyValuePairs);
}
```

However, you probably need to add additional formatting and perhaps change the name since it looks like you're including the contents in an HTML formatted string?

Comment: Signature probably shouldn't be `void`.

Comment: And that's still not going to help much in HTML. I think the OP should take a step back and think about what the method is really meant for before diving into fixing the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you might have been expecting is like this:

```
public static string outputDictionaryContents(Dictionary<string, int> list)
{
    return string.Join(
         Console.Out.NewLine,
         list.Select(pair => string.Format("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value)).ToArray());
}
```

Now, onto the real goal:

### Generating HTML

Or you could make it a bit friendlier for generating that HTML:

```
public static class FormatAsHtmlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> FormatAsHtml<K,V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dict, string format)
    {
        foreach (var pair in dict)
            yield return HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(string.Format(format, pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> FormatAsHtml<K,V>(this IDictionary<K, V> dict)
    {
        return FormatAsHtml("{0}, {1}");
    }
}
```

Which you could then use like:

```
// ...
Response.Write(dictionary.FormatAsHtml("<p>{0}<div style='value'>{1}</div>"));
```

Notes

- this extension type works for *any* type of dictionary, hashtable, key/value etc (you could add similar for lists/arrays by extending on IEnumerable
- I threw in **[HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)** to avoid the oft-forgotten escaping of un-HTML text

Answer (score 0):

Your method has no return value. It's `void`. This means it doesn't return anything that could be included in your string.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the return signature of the method `outputDictionaryContents` from `void` to perhaps a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to write to the console, you want to return the string and then pass that to the tw.WriteLine.

FYI, being static doesn't have anything to do with it.

So your function should look like this:

```
public static string outputDictionaryContents(Dictionary<string, int> list)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list)
            {
                StringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your static method `outputDictionaryContents` you write the output to the console and this method has no return value. Change the method like this:

```
public static string outputDictionaryContents(Dictionary<string, int> list) 
{
     StringBuilder returnValue = new StringBuilder(); 
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in list) 
     { 
          returnValue.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", new object[] { pair.Key, pair.Value }); 
     } 
     return returnValue.ToString();
}
```